# MVC4 API Post verb throws http 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, http, asp.net-web-api, http-verbs

I'm trying to create a REST api based on the Asp.Net MVC4 web api framework. The `GET` requests are working just fine. All other verbs are getting ignored by the server. 
It just says the following:

```
"No action was found on the controller 'Track' that matches the request."
```

Though the example error is from the Track controller all other controllers have the same problem.

This is the method on the controller Track I'm trying to call:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public Object Index(string token, string juke, string track)
    {
    }
```

I'v tried it using a `JSON` object like so:

```
{ "track": "0000", "juke": "0000" }
```

And I tried to use the "normal" way:

```
track=0000&juke=0000
```

The '0000' in the examples above are stand-ins for the real id's.

To be sure I'm also posting the `Register()` from `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultIndexBackEnd",
            routeTemplate: "back-end/{controller}/{token}",
            defaults: new { action = "Index", token = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultBackEnd",
            routeTemplate: "back-end/{controller}/{action}/{token}",
            defaults: new { token = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: What request url you are using?

Comment: I'm using: "/back-end/Track/0000". Again the "0000" is a stand-in for a real token.

Comment: Provide your view page code please.

Comment: It's web api so there is no view

Comment: I guess problem is you are posting 2 parameters and token in url. What if you modify route to remove token from there and accept is as post parameter? Post all there parameters.

Comment: Isn't it possible? It looks way nicer up in the url.

Comment: Well, I tested it. It doesn't change anything! Still the same 404 error.

Comment: More of a suggestion than an answer - you could try glimpse route debugging via nuget or http://getglimpse.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours of trying and researching articles I finally found [an article](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/) that precisely described my problem! If you're having the same problems, check out the article.

The problem was that I had to use the `[FromBody]` attribute on one parameter of the of the action. After moving `juke` and `track` into a model it finally worked as I had hoped.

Thanks everyone for the help, you all set me on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `TrackController`. Because you are using multiple parameters, they must be declared as optional.

```
[HttpPost]
public Object Index(string token="", string juke="", string track="")
{
}
```

You can make parameter `token` mandatory because `token` is declared as optional in routing configuration `DefaultIndexBackEnd`. I think using `[FromBody]` attribute is a good idea when there is more than one parameter for `POST` actions.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's important to understand how a typical REST Web API is supposed to work. Typically, it uses different HTTP verbs (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) for specific actions.

- GET: get an entity (or a collection) from the server
- POST: create a new entity
- PUT: update an existing entity
- DELETE: delete an existing entity

So when I see `[HttpPost]` on your `Index` action, it seems to me that the REST API pattern is broken.

Instead, in your controller you should have a `Entity Get(int id)` action (to get data) and a `void Post(Entity entity)` action to create new records.

No need to decorate your actions with `HttpGet` or `HttpPost`, the MVC Api framework will route the request to your action based on their names.

You can take a look at an example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/678138/MVC-using-Web-API-and-JQuery-to-GET-or-POST-Data).

Comment: I know, what this does is, it creates a track, the track param is a id used to create a cached copy from another external source and binds it to a juke. I will try the `Post()` and `Get()` actions.